# html5 - How i can disable horizontal scroll in responsive layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My layout is responsive, but if I change the size of the page it gets all messy.
I wonder how do I put a min-width on my body. so that the page can be resize to eg 500px wide.

**PS:**

I try set

```
body {
    min-width:400px;
}
```

but no work

*I use bootstrap*

**The problem is when I go to change the size of my window (page). when I leave the width very small components are misaligned.**

Comment: put `min-width` on the body?

Comment: no have effect, i use bootstrap, it has influence?

Answer (score 1):

You need to inspect the element with chrome/FF dev tools and make sure that bootsrap styling is not overriding your style. You can also try this:

```
 body {
    min-width:400px !important;
}
```

if that works, it means bootsrap is overriding the style.

Comment: I can block resize of my page ?

Comment: blocking resize all together is not a good idea, and also neglets the need for responsive design. you can limit the minimum size that fits your goals (i.e. doesn't break the layout) by setting the `min-width`, play with the site and see at what size it breaks and that is your limit.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really control the width of the `<body>` element, since it must fill the browser window. Try wrapping your content in a `<div>` with a min width.

Comment: That is not true, you can set the body width same as every other element

Answer (score 0):

Either your can give parent div for the layout with fixed width, then scroll bars comes if reduces the browser size, There won't be any mess.

it won't be no use controlling body width

another way give percentage value for the width size to maintain the layout structure